# Call GET from JavaScript and passing parameters

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor-2

Hi I am new to ASP Razor and i want to know how to call URL Action to pass parameter to GET verb  in the controller from JavaScript.Reloading the same page

```
javascript {
//some code 

@Url.Action("myAction","Conntroller", new { param1 = 123, param2 = 456}) // do not want to open        new window but to reload the page 

}


public ActionResult myAction(para1, param2)
{
return view()
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location.href = "siteurl/controller/action?param1=123&param2=456";
```

in your case:

```
location.href ="@Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { param1 = 123, param2 = 456})"
```

Comment: If you are using c# params use route values (like you initially did) to create links.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly for me

location.href = "@Url.Action("Action","Controller")?param1=" + value1+ "&param2=" + value2;

Comment: The better way would be to do what @free4ride did.  It is sloppy and clutters up the query string to attach your parameters in such a manner.  Just a hint for the future.